# About Frames in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am quite new to tkinter and I have a question:
When I run the following code, do I have to use `.pack()` on the frame (`app` in this case) or not?
Oh, and if I want to add a button, let's say, in the `__init__` of the `MainApp` class, after `tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)`, does the button get placed on the `app` frame or next to it?

Here's the code:

```
import tkinter as tk


class MainApp(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent


root = tk.Tk()
app = MainApp(root)
app.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a widget to be visible, you need to call either `grid`, `pack` or `place` (or embed it in a text or canvas widget). That is true for all widgets except the root window, including frames. It is one of those methods that actually draws the widget onto its parent widget.

Since `MainApp` is a subclass of `Frame` and a child of the root window, if you want it and its children to be visible, you'll need to call one of those methods.

> ... does the button get placed on the app frame or next to it?

I don't see any frame "next to it" -- you've only created a single frame inside the root window.

The whole reason to inherit from `Frame` is to create a container for other widgets. Generally speaking, every widget you create inside such a class should go in the frame of that class.

Also, as a rule of thumb the widget should *not* call `pack`, `place` or `grid` on itself. The function that creates the app (or in your case, the code in the global scope) should be responsible for calling one of those methods.

Also, you should  not rely on default attributes for those commands. The defaults are rarely enough. If you're using `pack`, for instance, you should always set a value for `fill`, and `expand`. It's usually good practice to always define `side` as well, but if it's the only widget in its parent you can accept the default.

```
root = tk.Tk()
app = MainApp(root)
app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I typically add buttons to the frame object or whatever the parent should be. It's a little bit clearer in code:

```
# Python 2.x example code
import Tkinter as tk

########################################################################
class App:
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        frame = tk.Frame(parent)
        frame.pack()

        print_btn = tk.Button(frame, text='Print',
                              command=lambda: self.onPrint('Print'))
        print_btn.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        close_btn = tk.Button(frame, text='close', command=frame.quit)
        close_btn.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onPrint(self, num):
        print "You just printed something"

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

As you can see, I add a couple of buttons to the frame by setting the frame as their parent and then packing them. The frame itself is packed implicitly to the root since the root is the parent of the frame.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! But I still don't know the answers to the questions that I asked. If you don't mind, please answer them. ;)

Comment: As I mentioned, yes you do want to call pack on the frame object. To add buttons to the frame, set the frame as the parent. If you want the buttons next to the frame, then set the `parent` argument in the `__init__` as their parent too.

Comment: Personally I think it's a bad practice for a widget to call `pack` (or `grid` or `place`) on itself. In the case of a root application class it's not so bad, but as a general habit it limits reuse.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!